# Swift: How to clear collectionView for reuse in a collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collectionView that is inside a collectionViewCell and the collectionView isn't getting cleared correctly when the cell is being reused.

Code:

```
class TweetCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var mediaCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: NSCollectionLayoutDimension.fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: NSCollectionLayoutDimension.fractionalHeight(1)
        )
        
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: size)
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: size, subitem: item, count: 1)
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 4
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .paging
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return cv
    }()

    var tweet: Tweet? {
        didSet {
            if let tweet = tweet {

                //Setup other UI elements
                nameLabel.text = tweet.name ?? ""
                twitterHandleLabel.text = tweet.twitterHandle ?? ""
                profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: profileImageUrl) 
            }
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    
        setupViews()
    }
 
    func setupViews() {
    
 
        let mainStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
            userHStack,
            mediaCollectionView,
            bottomHStack
        ])
    
        mainStack.axis = .vertical
        mainStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
        addSubview(mainStack)
        mainStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        mainStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        mainStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        mainStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
        //Must lower priority otherwise autolayout will complain
        heightConstraint = mediaCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        heightConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(999)
    
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    
        mediaCollectionView.reloadData()
        tweet = nil
    }
} 

extension TweetCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource  {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tweet?.mediaArray?.count ?? 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        return cell
    }
}

//HomeController that displays the feed
class HomeController: UIViewController {

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: NSCollectionLayoutDimension.fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: NSCollectionLayoutDimension.estimated(500)
        )
        
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: size)
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: size, subitem: item, count: 1)
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.register(TweetCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return cv
    }()
    
    var tweets: [Tweet]?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupViews()
        fetchData()
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        let accessToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constants.UserDefaults.UserAccessTokenKey) ?? ""
        let secretToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constants.UserDefaults.UserSecretTokenKey) ?? ""
                
        TwitterClient.shared.fetchHomeTimeline(accessToken: accessToken, secretToken: secretToken) { (tweets) in
            self.tweets = tweets
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func setupViews() {

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    
}

extension HomeController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tweets?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TweetCell
        cell.tweet = tweets?[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
}
```

If I hard code the `numberOfItemsInSection` to a random integer, the `mediaCollectionView` displays the number of cells correctly. However when set dynamically to `tweet?.mediaArray?.count`, the number of cells are no longer correct. I believe it is due to the reuse of the collectionViewCell as the counts of these cells starts jumping around as I scroll through the collectionView.

How do I properly reset the collectionView inside TweetCell?

UPDATE:

Attempt 2: -

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    
    mediaCollectionView.reloadData()
    tweet = nil
    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```

Above didn't quite work as well.

Comment: Try doing what `prepareForResuse` is doing in the top level `cellForItemAt`

Comment: @gkpln3 I don't quite understand, would you be able to explain?

Comment: prepareForReuse is called when TweetCell is dequeued. Also mediaCollectionView isn't reloaded after set tweet model object. Can you show full code, please?

Comment: @ezaji I have updated with all the code that I think are relevant. Have omitted UI constraints code in TweetCell for brevity.

Comment: First, I think you should get rid of `mediaCollectionView.reloadData()` from `prepareForReuse()` and instead of `tweet = nil`, try setting individual properties to `nil` like `profileImageView.image = nil`.

Comment: mediaCollectionView is depend on Tweet model object. `prepareForReuse()` is called when `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TweetCell` is called in HomeController. Then you set instance of Tweet, but mediaCollectionView isn't reloaded at that time. Try to `reloadData()` in didSet observer of tweet property.

Comment: Also Kevvv's advice is acceptable.

Comment: @ezaji reloadData() in didSet appears to have worked for me, ie the cell counts are displayed correctly now. I did not attempt kevvv's solution on setting individual properties to nil as I'm not quite sure how to set mediaCollectionView to nil.

Comment: I recommend you to read documentation about `prepareForReuse()` method. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse Pay attention to Discuss section.

Comment: @ezaji I have read the docs, and I see two main points. 1) call super anyways and 2) not to assign new data. I believe I have implemented both, ie calling super and not assigning any new data. Am I missing something?

Comment: Main key is "use it to reset properties to their default values and generally make the view ready to use again". Calling `reloadData()` in this method isn't about resetting to default value. Resetting `profileImageView.image` to default image (placeholder) is more appropriate. Image for profileImageView is downloaded. User can see previous image before downloading ends.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I think you have to implement the regular protocols inside the cell and refactoring all your code.

I mean UICollectionViewDelegate (or flownDelegate) and UICollectionViewDataSource.

```
class TweetCell: UICollectionViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
```

...

Comment: Hi I don't quite understand, I've already implemented delegate and datasource methods via the TweetCell extension.

Comment: Have you see in the debug if when the collection pops you have some constraint errors/conflicts?

Comment: No, there isn't any constraint errors/conflicts.

Comment: Probably I got it. it's a non sense to use a reload collection data inside a prepareForReuse cell. As you I'll refactoring the code in the "classic" way, mainly split the collection code with the cell code (and relative xib). So it's easier to debug the things.